# Name of a salon or hall in which a rock band would perform music

Tags: word-request

What do we call a music salon or hall in which a rock band would perform, in English? I want words both for a place with roof and without roof (like an amphitheater) please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words ["concert hall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_concert_halls) are often used (for a place with a roof); even though these used to be constructed centuries ago for classical music, nowadays they're used for all kinds of music, including rock music. There is (AFAIK) no word or phrase exclusively used for rock music.

Note that "music hall" is only slightly less commonly used than "concert hall"; see this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concert+hall%2C+music+hall&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconcert%20hall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusic%20hall%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I might use *concert venue*, though that would also cover "non-constructed" locations like the Great Lawn in Central Park NYC, or a beach somewhere...

Comment: OP said they wanted a term that covered outdoor amphitheaters as well. A "concert hall" is definitely indoors.

Comment: An outdoor venue would need a bandshell otherwise it's just a stage.

Answer (score 41):

"Venue" is the overarching term that describes a location where anything can be performed.

> **[venue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/venue)** (n): The place where something happens, especially an organized event such as a concert, conference, or sports competition.

It doesn't matter if it is an outdoor stage, stadium, public park, convention center, sports arena, theater, or even an actual performance hall.  All of these can be considered *venues* for organized events.

"Music hall" or "music salon" sound old-fashioned to me, but seem to still be in use for older, landmark buildings.  "Concert hall" is also used, although this seems to be more a place for a symphony orchestra than a rock band.

Comment: As someone who has been heavily into the rock scene from both a spectator and performer point of view, this is the most common way to refer to the performance space. The only other name we use for it is the specific name of what it is (park, church, bar, etc.) but even that is considerably less common than simply "venue".

Comment: Being both the drummer and the guy with the van, I always needed to know what the next venue was, so I knew how to get there and how big the stage was. We played auditoriums, but never a concert hall. Those (are where the orchestra plays) would be some weird transient state before you were big enough to play actual *venues* (ones that are solely devoted to music; not just a dive bar - but with TicketMaster and all that jazz). After that you're on to stadiums and sports arenas.

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for **[auditorium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/auditorium)**:

> A large room for public meetings or performances.

That might not be a perfect fit, as it usually implies a closed room rather than one open to the air.  But its etymology does connect it very strongly with sound (through ***audio***).

Comment: Yes, but I think _auditorium_ suggests the place is not intended (primarily) for music performances.

Comment: Just as a "concert hall" is primarily *not* for rock music.

Answer (score 3):

For small to medium sized venues (see other answer), an informal term for this would be ['club' or 'nightclub'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nightclub).  For rock music specifically you might use 'rock-club'.

Comment: Usually DJs play at clubs, not rock bands.

Comment: Plenty of clubs feature rock bands regularly, there's nothing unusual about it.

Comment: @Mazura Here's the [ngram for 'rock club'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rock+club&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crock%20club%3B%2Cc0).  This term peaked around the height of the grunge era.  In the hipster crowd, you go see a 'show' at a 'club'.  Seeing a 'concert' at a 'concert hall' is for the stadium rock crowd or cosmic cowboy type of rock music.

Comment: Ain't nobody *making it rain* to rock music.... Your definition of 'club' is obviously different than mine. In mine, the word is always proceeded by a *da*, and followed by a *yo*.